# How to polish the narrow side of Stainless Steel gate

Tags: steel, finishing, corrosion, welding, stainless

Due to welding, the SS gate looks unpolished.

[image]

The problem is buffing wheel is not reaching the edges.

It's too narrow to buff the corners and edges.

Likewise I have installed Stainless Steel Hand rail and that also has places where we can not buff due to narrow edges.

Any ideas on how should I proceed ?

Comment: Can you remove it for polishing? That will make your life a lot easier than trying to polish it in place.

Comment: That's what I thought But they have welded it completely , it's not removable , probably I have to unweld the few permanent hinges on the top and bottom.

Comment: Horrible welding job.

Comment: Those pins should knock out, or at least you can unbolt the whole thing.

Comment: @KMJ - The whole gate is welded so it's not possible to unbolt but I think I should be able to knock out the weld and try ? but is there any special buffing tool or something which can work well in the narrow space.

Comment: Narrow wheels exist.

Comment: @KMJ - I'm after narrow wheels.Probably I should find one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below cones are usually used for polishing car like narrower areas like rim of the car etc.

I think you can use this for buffing your stainless steel. I'm not an expert try and see for yourself

[image]

Or

You might buy stone based buffing wheels in cone shape. You might be able to find easily

[image]

Comment: after buffing, I would immediately spray protective coating on it. The welds tend to rust first.

Comment: @Nelson - What kind of coating should be sprayed ?

Comment: Metal Lacquer Finish in spray can form. Follow instructions on can. You don't even need to do anything to ventilate it since it is outside. Will help it last much longer. Do multiple coats if you have the time. This is easier than to fix it when it eats right through the welds.